# Problem changing face_recognize package parameter

Tags: ros, parameter, face-recognition

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I follow the procedure in face_recognition wiki page,and successful run the Fserver and Fclient. But It can't recognize my face ,It seem confidence_value set to 0.88 is too high for my camera, so I want to change the parameter.
Since I can't see confidence_value parameter using "rosparam list". I want to know how can I change the confidence_value parameter.
And I notice that in wiki page, parameter name always will has a prefix ～，but face_recognize parameter do not have one. is this make the different.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64189/problem-changing-face_recognize-package-parameter/) by [AnsonTao](https://answers.ros.org/users/4563/ansontao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-06-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In face_recognition.cpp, line 60, you can change the confidence value in the source code and compile the package again :-)

---

Originally posted by [Pouyan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1471/pouyan/) with karma: 143 on 2013-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0